# Rabbitmq Consumers Stops consuming - java client

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq in a microservice environment, and I use it to send messages and events to other services.
my projects are java spring boot and I am using rabbitmq java client's latest version.
The problem is some consumers stop consuming at a random point in time, and the only way to get them going again is to restart the application. I have not been able to find a pattern. here is what I have done and know:

- some consumers stop working not all of them.
- I have enabled auto-recovery option
- publishers of the same application have no problems.
- This is my rabbitmq client: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.17.0
- I have monitored both java applications and rabbimq memory and CPU usages, they do not have memory or CPU shortages
- I have read the following links and they did not solve my problem:

[RabbitMQ - surviving a consumer disconnection using DefaultConsumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941644/rabbitmq-surviving-a-consumer-disconnection-using-defaultconsumer)

[RabbitMQ Connect/Disconnect Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338247/rabbitmq-connect-disconnect-notifications)

[RabbitMQ disconnect me after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811786/rabbitmq-disconnect-me-after-some-time)

[RabbitMQ java client stops consuming messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771664/rabbitmq-java-client-stops-consuming-messages)

[Temporarily stop consuming RabbitMQ messages and resume later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033118/temporarily-stop-consuming-rabbitmq-messages-and-resume-later)

[RabbitMQ consumer stops receiving messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732936/rabbitmq-consumer-stops-receiving-messages)

[RabbitMQ message consumers stop consuming messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284731/rabbitmq-message-consumers-stop-consuming-messages)

- this is how I have coded my base consumer :

```java
public abstract class BaseConsumer implements Consumer {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseConsumer.class);

    protected Connection connection;
    protected Channel channel;
    protected String exchangeType;
    protected String exchangeName;
    protected String queueName;
    protected String routingKey;
    protected String consumerTag;
    protected String deadLetterExchangeName;
    protected String deadLetterQueueName;
    protected String deadLetterRoutingKey;
    protected boolean autoDelete;
    protected boolean durableQueue;
    protected boolean exclusiveQueue;
    protected boolean requiresConfirm;

    protected BaseConsumer(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.requiresConfirm = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void consume() {
        consumeMessage();
    }

    protected void consumeMessage() {
        try {
            Channel channel = createChannel();
            declareChannel(channel);
            log.info(String.format("%s: [*] Waiting for %s. To exit press CTRL+C", getClassName(), queueName));
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, !requiresConfirm, consumerTag, getConsumer(channel));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private DefaultConsumer getConsumer(Channel channel) {
        return new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
                handleMessageProcess(body, envelope);
            }
        };
    }

    private void handleMessageProcess(byte[] body, Envelope envelope) {
        String message = new String(body);
        log.info(String.format("%s: [x] received '%s'", getClassName(), message));
        long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
        if (validateMessage(message)) {
            log.info("validation was Successful");
            if (requiresConfirm) {
                log.info("******** handling delivery");
                try {
                    basicConsume(message);
                    ackMessage(channel, deliveryTag);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(String.format("Consume Failed Moving Message To DLQ. Error Is: \n%s", e));
                    nackMessage(channel, deliveryTag);
                }
            } else {
                basicConsume(message);
            }
        } else {
            log.info("validation was not Successful");
            messageNotValidProcess(message, deliveryTag);
        }
    }

    protected void ackMessage(Channel channel, long deliveryTag) {
        try {
            log.info("Message was acknowledged");
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void nackMessage(Channel channel, long deliveryTag) {
        try {
            log.info("Message Not Acknowledged");
            channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, false);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected boolean validateMessage(String message) {
        return ValidationUtils.isJsonObject(message);
    }

    protected void basicConsume(String message) {
        log.info(" [x] consumed '" + message + "' (do nothing - not implemented)");
    }

    protected void messageNotValidProcess(String message, long deliveryTag) {
        log.info(String.format("[x] %d consuming was unsuccessful. %s is not valid %s", deliveryTag, queueName, message));
    }

    private Channel createChannel() throws IOException {
        if (this.channel == null || !this.channel.isOpen()) {
            this.channel = connection.createChannel();
            try {
                declareChannel(channel);
            } catch (IOException | ShutdownSignalException exception) {
                this.channel = connection.createChannel();
                log.warn("Queue parameters had changed, trying recreating them...");
                deleteQueueIfEmpty(channel, queueName);
                if (deadLetterQueueName != null) {
                    deleteQueueIfEmpty(channel, deadLetterQueueName);
                }
                declareChannel(channel);
            }
        }
        return channel;
    }

    private void declareChannel(Channel channel) throws IOException {
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exchangeName, exchangeType);
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        if (deadLetterExchangeName != null && deadLetterRoutingKey != null && deadLetterQueueName != null) {
            args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", deadLetterExchangeName);
            args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", deadLetterRoutingKey);
            channel.exchangeDeclare(deadLetterExchangeName, exchangeType);
            channel.queueDeclare(deadLetterQueueName, false, false, false, null);
            channel.queueBind(deadLetterQueueName, deadLetterExchangeName, deadLetterRoutingKey);
        }
        channel.queueDeclare(queueName, durableQueue, autoDelete, exclusiveQueue, args);
        channel.queueBind(queueName, exchangeName, routingKey);

        if (requiresConfirm) {
            channel.confirmSelect();
            channel.addConfirmListener(this::confirmed, this::notConfirmed);
        }
    }

    private void deleteQueueIfEmpty(Channel channel, String queueName) {
        log.info(String.format("Deleting Queue: %s", queueName));
        try {
            channel.queueDelete(queueName, false, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(String.format("Couldn't delete queue with name: %s", queueName));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void confirmed(long sequenceNumber, boolean multiple) {
        // code when message is confirmed
        log.info(String.format("Message with sequenceNumber: %d is confirmed.", sequenceNumber));
    }

    protected void notConfirmed(long sequenceNumber, boolean multiple) {
        // code when message is nack-ed
        log.info(String.format("Message with sequenceNumber: %d is NOT confirmed!!!", sequenceNumber));
    }

    private String getClassName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

I have many classes extending this abstract class and implementing the parts that I need to. this is a serious problem for me because some features of our application does not work properly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, check that you set up enough Memory to your java application..

Comment: I have monitored both java applications and rabbimq memory and CPU usages, they do not have memory or CPU shortages.

Comment: `deleteQueueIfEmpty()` gives me pause.  If you happen to delete a queue that has a listener attached, would it not also then remove that listener?  Does every instance of BaseConsumer have a one-to-one relationship with the queue it's listening on?

Comment: for each instance of our application, every instance of BaseConsumer has a one-to-one relationship with the queue it's listening on. even if the queue is deleted and the listeners removed, new listeners will be added with the new instances of the application going online. I hope I understood your question correctly. if not let me know so I can explain more

Comment: Did you find the cause and fix for the issue?

Comment: @abbaspiplodawala I could not find a fix for it. it still happens. I made it better with autorecovery. I tested different numbers and currently 15 seems to work better, but it still happens